# Best way to learn React with Babel from scratch?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I have an idea for a game and I will try to create it.
It is a simple multiplayer game that runs in a browser.
I was recommended to use React.js and Firebase. 
So I paid 60 dollars for a video tutorial that built an app using these technologies, perfect! Unfortunately, it uses the JSX transformer that was deprecated, and now I have learned that I should use something called Babel instead.
What I wonder is if you can recommend me some tutorial that teach me React with Babel from scratch. I googled a lot but I could not find anything directed at noobs

Comment: This is a very open question, so I'm afraid it will be closed fairly quickly – Stack Overflow doesn't work well for questions that have any number of subjective answers. That being said, can I suggest you [try my own free online React + Babel tutorial](http://www.hackingwithreact.com/)?

Comment: @TwoStraws this was exactly what I was looking for. Very thorough!

Comment: hello @hellogoodnight, check the https://reactjs.co it's a free ReactJS for Dummies book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the react site tutorial (http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) they show a post JSX transformer method using babel. You should also look at some of the starter packages to see what style of organizing and building react works best for you. Here are a couple;
https://github.com/jmarkstevens/ReactPatterns

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a forum for this sort of question and the question might get flagged as off-topic, but for what it's worth, since learning this stuff is hard for beginners, I suggest going to the `redux` library [github page](https://github.com/rackt/redux) and watching the 30 free tutorial videos, then downloading the examples and using their 'webpack' configuration. The examples come with the pre-installed set of tools for transpiling JSX using Babel. You could look at the "counter" example since it doesn't have much redux at all (though I suggest using it anyways).

Otherwise you could be using `gulp` and `browserify` to babelify your code but again, the question is broad and should be more of a forum post so that a thread could be started for discussion.